# Why is it always the case that, given an equivalence relation R on a set X and a $x \in X$, that x is equivalent to itself?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

Why is it always the case that, given an equivalence relation R on a set X and a $x \in X$, that x is equivalent to itself?

According to my book, this is due to the reflexivity of $R$ and consequently $x \in [x]_R$, but isn't an equivalence relation supposed to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive - not just reflexive?

I've cross-checked this with some other books, and they all say the same thing. I don't get it, how can $x \in [x]$ if x only satisfies reflexivity?

Comment: Your question is unclear - $x\in [x]$ is what it means to be reflexive, one of three conditions to be an equivalence relation.

Comment: Also, you should put all essential information in the body of your question. Don't leave anything important in the title only!

Comment: @ZacharySelk Except, only a few pages prior to this, I was taught that, given an equivalence relation R, $[x]=\{y : y \in X \, and \, y \, R \, x \}$

Answer (score 2):

You're mixed up about something, and it's really not clear what.

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation.

$R$ is reflexive. Yes, $R$ is also symmetric and transitive, but that doesn't change the fact that $R$ is reflexive.

We can prove $xRx$ using only the fact that $R$ is reflexive. That doesn't prevent $R$ from having additional properties beyond being reflexive.

The above paragraph also applies to showing $x \in [x]_R$. (depending on the definition of $[x]_R$, I suppose)

Reflexivity is a property of relations, not elements. It doesn't make sense to say that $x$ is reflexive.

---

If having the facts of the matter laid out doesn't help, you'll probably have to give a better explanation of how and why you've arrived at the the things you think are true and at the questions you have and why you're confused about them.

Comment: Alright, I'll try. So, in my book, given an equivalence relation R, an equivalence class is defined to be $[a]=\{ b : b \in A \, , \, b \, R \, a \}$. Also, because of the reflexivity of R, $x \in [x]$. But why? Shouldn't reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity hold, not just reflexivity?